# The following _TypeError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: flutter, dart, android-debug, uncaughtexceptionhandler, flutter-exception

```
import 'package:first/app_styles.dart';
import 'package:first/custom_tab_indicator.dart';
import 'package:first/size_config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({super.key});
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
         body: HomePage(), 
          ),
     );
   }
 }
 class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   const HomePage({super.key});
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
     return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: kBackgroundColor,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 52,
              left: 24,
              right: 24,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                'All Inboxes',
                style: kJakartaHeading1.copyWith(
                      color: kDarkColor,
                      fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * kHeading1
                ),
                ),
               const Icon(Icons.expand_more)
                    ],
                  ),
               Text('Total 2500 Messages , 3 Unread',
               style: kJakartaBodyMedium.copyWith(
                color: kParagraphColor,
                fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * kBody1,
               ),
               )
                ],
              ),
             const CircleAvatar(
                maxRadius: 26,
                backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
                foregroundImage: NetworkImage("https://scontent.fbbi3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/290811895_737811837530600_5631746207860732425_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=174925&_nc_ohc=bC4YJN-G7XMAX9ScsYO&_nc_ht=scontent.fbbi3-1.fna&oh=00_AfDDgP91zqk5w95CPZegQJrNGLNGAOnJ2c1bPejkP8drGQ&oe=642CDE70"),
              )
            ]
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 28,
            color: kBackgroundColor,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 98,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 10,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context,index)  {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: index == 0 ? 24 : 0,
                    right: index == 9 ? 24 : 8,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                           const CircleAvatar(
                               maxRadius: 36,
                               backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
                               foregroundImage: NetworkImage("https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconfinder.com%2Ficons%2F7123025%2Flogo_google_g_icon&psig=AOvVaw1P3y-6z6_Kqz7EkyFOa6mR&ust=1680431544395000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCLiI8729iP4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            right: 0,
                          left: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 2,
                                horizontal: 8,
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                color: kPrimaryColor,
                              ),
                              child: IntrinsicWidth(
                                child: Text('12',
                              style: kJakartaBodyBold.copyWith(
                                color: kWhiteColor,
                                fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * kBody2,
                              ),
                              ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8,
                      ),
                      Text('Google',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: kJakartaBodyMedium.copyWith(
                        color: kParagraphColor,
                        fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * kBody1,
                      ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 48,
            color: kBackgroundColor,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 30,
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -24, 0),
            decoration:const BoxDecoration(
              color: kWhiteColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
                topRight: Radius.circular(32)
              )
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 24
            ),
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -36, 0),
            height: 30,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: DefaultTabController(
                      length: 3,
                      child: TabBar(
                        labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only( right: 24),
                        indicatorWeight: 8,
                        isScrollable: true,
                        labelColor: kDarkColor,
                        labelStyle: kJakartaBodyBold.copyWith(
                          fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * kBody1,
                        ),
                        unselectedLabelColor: kDark40Color,
                        indicator: RoundedRectangleTabIndicator(color: kPrimaryColor, weight: 4, width: 24, padding: 12),
                      splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory,
                      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.focused) ? null : Colors.transparent,)
                     ,tabs: const [
                     Tab(text: 'Primary',),
                     Tab(text: 'Socia;',),
                     Tab(text: 'Forums',),
                     ]
                     ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox( height: 19.5,
               child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
               children: [
                const Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                const SizedBox(width: 24),
                Text('Edit',
                style: kJakartaBodyBold.copyWith(
                  color: kDark40Color,
                          fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * kBody1,
                        ),
                )
               ],
               ),
               )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Container(
          //   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
          //   transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -36, 0),
          //   child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: ),
          // )
        ],
      ),
     );
   }
 }
```

I am new to flutter .I was trying to run the app but it shows this error.
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]):
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
HomePage HomePage:file:///D:/UI%20under%20FLutter/first/lib/main.dart:16:16

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      new RoundedRectangleTabIndicator (package:first/custom_tab_indicator.dart:11:65)
#1      HomePage.build (package:first/main.dart:173:36)
#2      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5038:49)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:15)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:5)
#5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4950:5)
#6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4944:5)
...     Normal element mounting (25 frames)
#31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3953:16)
#32     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6512:36)
#33     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6524:32)
...     Normal element mounting (318 frames)
#351    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3953:16)
#352    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6512:36)
#353    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6524:32)
...     Normal element mounting (452 frames)
#805    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3953:16)
#806    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3682:18)
#807    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1176:16)
#808    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1145:5)
#809    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree. (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1092:18)
#810    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2682:19)
#811    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1091:13)
#812    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:926:7)
#813    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget. (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:906:7)
#817    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:26)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

One or more of the parameter values you are passing to RoundedRectangleTabIndicator should be a double. You are using integers. The information you get in the stack is quite specific and useful. You need to read and understand it.

Also your IDE should be able to indicate to you what the type of the parameters are.